# SQL Server - Merge multiple query results into one result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three queries which return one columns each.

```
SELECT Name FROM Tenant
SELECT Name FROM Space
SELECT ID FROM Contracts
```

The table definitions are:

```
Tenant    (ID, Name)
Space     (ID, Name, TenantID)
Contracts (ID, TenantID)
```

The information that I have in these tables is:

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Tenant1 |
|  2 | Tenant2 |
|  3 | Tenant3 |
+----+---------+

+----+------+----------+
| id | name | tenantID |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | S1   |        1 |
|  2 | S2   |        1 |
|  3 | S3   |        2 |
|  4 | S4   |        3 |
|  5 | S5   |        3 |
+----+------+----------+

+----+----------+
| id | tenantID |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        2 |
|  4 |        2 |
|  5 |        2 |
|  6 |        3 |
+----+----------+
```

How can I write a query to achieve the below structure?

```
+----------+-------+----------+
|  tenant  | space | contract |
+----------+-------+----------+
| tenant 1 | S1    |        1 |
|          | S2    |        2 |
| tenant 2 | S3    |        3 |
|          |       |        4 |
|          |       |        5 |
| tenant 3 | S4    |        6 |
|          | S5    |          |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

I have links between Tenant and Contracts table, but I don't want them to take into account the spaces between tenants and I don't want the values in any of the columns to be duplicate.

I've tried using joins, but they obviously duplicate the values in the columns if matches exist between them.

```
SELECT T.NAME 'Tname',
    S.NAME 'Sname',
    C.ID
FROM Tenant T
LEFT JOIN Space S
    ON T.ID = S.TenantID
LEFT JOIN Contracts C
    ON T.ID = C.TenantID
```

I've also tried correlating this into a subquery and using `ROW_NUMBER()` and combining with some `CASE` statements to achieve the desired format, but wasn't very successful.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2a288/1) with some sample data.

Any suggestions/comments or links that could help are very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you use the result for? Formattning and removing duplicate text is something you normally do in the client application or report

Comment: @adrianm I know and I agree with you, but unfortunately I cannot make modifications to the application (I don't have access), only in SQL. I use the query to output a part of a report.

Comment: How do you relate between 'Contracts' and 'Spaces'? Tenant 1 has two contracts and two spaces but how do you know which contract is for which space?

Comment: @Bjorn That's the idea, that there are no links. It's just an enumeration of what `Spaces` and `Contracts` a `Tenant` has. There is no link between them, just a "line break" once you reach a new tenant. That is why in my example query I do not do the JOIN on `Contracts` between `Contracts` and `Space` but with `Tenant` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH SpaceRow AS (
    SELECT tenantid
          ,name
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenantid ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber
    FROM Space
)
,ContractRow AS (
    SELECT tenantid
          ,id
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenantid ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber
    FROM Contracts
)
,SpaceContracts AS (
    SELECT COALESCE(SpaceRow.tenantid, ContractRow.tenantid) AS tenantid
          ,COALESCE(SpaceRow.RowNumber, ContractRow.RowNumber) AS RowNumber
          ,SpaceRow.name AS SpaceName
          ,ContractRow.id AS ContractId
    FROM SpaceRow
         FULL OUTER JOIN ContractRow
              ON SpaceRow.tenantid = ContractRow.tenantid
                 AND SpaceRow.RowNumber = ContractRow.RowNumber
)
SELECT CASE WHEN SpaceContracts.RowNumber IS NULL  
                 OR SpaceContracts.RowNumber = 1
            THEN Tenant.name 
            ELSE NULL
        END AS TenantName
       ,SpaceContracts.SpaceName
       ,SpaceContracts.ContractId
FROM Tenant
     LEFT JOIN SpaceContracts
         ON SpaceContracts.tenantid = Tenant.id
ORDER BY Tenant.id
        ,SpaceContracts.RowNumber
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just observed that this actually duplicates the "Spaces" per Tenant. I will try to modify your code to achieve the desired output.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean with duplicates. SqlFiddle shows your desired output.

Comment: You are right and based on the data that I provided, your solution is correct. Re-marked your answer as correct. I'll fiddle around with the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this might be one solution to your problem:

```
; WITH spaces AS (
SELECT t.ID AS tID, t.NAME AS tName, s.NAME AS sName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY s.ID) AS sSeq
FROM tenant t
LEFT JOIN space s ON t.ID = s.TenantID ),
contrs AS (
SELECT t.ID AS tID, t.NAME AS tName, c.ID AS cID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY c.Id) AS tSeq
FROM tenant t
LEFT JOIN contracts c ON t.ID = c.TenantID ),
partial AS (
SELECT s.tName AS tName, s.sName AS sName, c.cID As cID
FROM spaces s
LEFT JOIN contrs c ON s.tID = c.tID AND s.sSeq = c.tSeq )
SELECT (SELECT NAME FROM tenant WHERE tenant.ID = c.TenantID) AS tName, NULL AS sName, c.ID AS cID
FROM contracts c
WHERE c.ID NOT IN (SELECT cID FROM partial WHERE cID IS NOT NULL)

UNION ALL 

SELECT *
FROM partial

ORDER By tName
```

The above CTE-based query produces the following output:

```
tName   sName   cID
--------------------
Tenant1 S1      1
Tenant1 S2      2
Tenant2 S3      3  
Tenant2 NULL    4
Tenant2 NULL    5
Tenant3 S4      6
Tenant3 S5      NULL
```

which is close enough to the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is what you want to be doing?  It is more informative to show all results, including the data that should be in those spaces you want.  By removing fields simply because it shows that value in the field above, you are restricting any filtering that people may want to do further down the line.

Also, given the data you provided, your results are wrong, for example Tenant 1 would have 4 records not 2.  They have 2 Spaces and 2 Contracts, with no direct join between spaces and contracts, meaning you would have 2x2=4 records for Tenant 1.  All in all, your output should have 9 records, not 7.  You can't change this given the current structure.

If a manager has requested that data in a report be presented like this, I would suggest explaining to them that it less useful in this format, and they can do more with it if everything is included.  For example if they want to see it in Excel, how would they filter it to everything for Tenant 1?  In the requested format you would only see one record if you put a filter on Tenant 1.  Or if this should ever be used in a csv, incorrect data would be loaded.  There are no advantages to how you want it laid out, other than aesthetics which remove functionality.

Comment: I have already explained to them all of the points that you have mentioned, but they want to go for the aesthetics feature over the functionality. Even if they're exporting into Excel, they said they won't filter anything. They refused the initial version which was developed exactly as you said (links between contracts and spaces, as I also see it being as normal) because of the "clutter of data". But, they see me as "the expert": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg&spfreload=10

Comment: lol the video looks fairly accurate.  Sounds like you are in a difficult situation, when I've been in similar situations in previous companies, I've had to explain to the management that they can either have correct data that isn't as pretty, or they can pretty data that isn't correct, they can't have it both ways; 'you are the expert' after all, so give them your expert opinion.  I'm sure it's possible, but to be honest, if they get their way every time, they will make your life hell going forward, they should respect your opinion, explain the limitations, it will be worth it in the long run.

Comment: Alternatively, SQL Server Reporting Services can get rid of duplicated fields for presentation purposes like this, but you will still have 4 records for Tenant 1, because that is what is *correct*, it would just lay it out so you only see "Tenant 1" in the first row that's relevant.  Having said that, if you only have access to SQL Server like you said to adrianm, then I don't know what chance you have of getting SSRS installed, and time to learn you way around it, your managers sound difficult.

Comment: Actually we have an inhouse built reporting system which is similar to SSRS, so even more constraints apply (because it's inhouse we have "custom things" - again, not developed by me, I'm just forced to use it). And because we have all of these constraints, the format in which I'm trying to export the data is the easiest I see to integrate with another part of the report, which has already been written. So, anyway, although I am "the expert", I still have to find a way to make "7 rows displayed, 4 with black ink and 3 with transparent ink", and I don't know where I can get transparent ink...